# Python - string and tuple comparison

Tags: python, string, tuples

How to compare a string and a tuple, raise an error if the string has repeated letters , for example `('PTMP',('P','T','M'))`  will say `raise ValueError(...)` but if the tuple had an extra P, like in  `('P','T','M','P')` the answer would be valid?

```
def whatever(string,tup): 
    for j in string: 
        if j not in tup: 
            raise ValueError('') 
        for u in tup: 
            if j not in tup: raise ValueError('')
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare the counts of the letters in the two?  [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the natural solution there

Comment: Can you write your code ?

Comment: What code showed the ValueError?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far , and i you did not - close the question since you will not receive answer here.

Comment: def whatever(string,tup):
       for j in string:
              if j not in tup:
                     raise ValueError('') 
       for u in tup:
              if j not in tup:
                     raise ValueError('')

Comment: I edited that snippet into your question, but I had to guess at the indentation, could you double check?

Answer (score 0):

If the characters are supposed to be in the same order in the string and the tuple then this will work for you:

```
if (len(x) == len(y) and all(x[i] == y[i] for i in range(len(x)))):
    raise ValueError()
else:
    # Be happy
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is that the string doesn't have more of any particular letter than the tuple, you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subtraction

```
from collection import Counter

def can_be_built(s, tup):
   if Counter(s) - Counter(tup):
       # The string does not use letters the tuple doesn't have
       return True
   else:
       return False
```